# Images from public/assets folder in Ember returning 404

Tags: image, ember.js, assets, public

I am trying to create my first ember app, and I started fleshing out the landing page. I tried to create a billboard section at the top and placed an image in it with an inline style

```
background-image: url('/assets/images/photo.png')
```

I read that you are supposed to put all your images in an assets folder in the public directory which I did, but I am getting a 404 response for that image.

```
http://localhost:4200/assets/images/photo.png
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove `assets` from URL.

`background-image: url('/images/photo.png')`

`http://localhost:4200/images/photo.png`